SVG Mask Effects / CSS Filtering - "Hue Change + Bright/Glow Edge"
Specific problem per bot comment:
I cannot figure out how to get a highlighted/glowing edge on a svg like this.
Bright Edge SVG
All kinds of variations playing around with fill, fill opacity, stroke, stroke opacity, stroke width, with and without the filter.
In hindsight I probably could have done this in photoshop a lot quicker and been done days ago. But I've invested so much time and I thought it would be nice to be able to simply change the color via hue-rotate.


.hero-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 508px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.masked-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  /* Does nothing in this example, was from other tests */
}


/* Specific filters for each hero section */

.red-neon .masked-image {
  filter: brightness(1) sepia(1) hue-rotate(0deg) saturate(5) contrast(2);
}

.border-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="hero-section red-neon">
    <svg class="border-overlay" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <mask id="parallelogram-mask-red" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <path d="M5 498V71L85 2V429L5 498Z" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="1" filter="url(#neon-filter-red)" />
        </mask>

        <filter id="neon-filter-red">
           <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5" result="blur" />
           <feMerge>
              <feMergeNode in="blur" />
              <feMergeNode in="blur" />
              <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
           </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/816608/pexels-photo-816608.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="Image with Mask" class="masked-image" style="mask: url(#parallelogram-mask-red); -webkit-mask: url(#parallelogram-mask-red);">
  </div>
</div>




Can you write your code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

What does _content/App.Shared/galaxy.jpg look like?

Here's a link about how to make a duotone filter with SVG filters: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/05/svg-filter-effects-duotone-images-with-fecomponenttransfer/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
